# How to log a driver's location and online status realtime with minimal load to the server?

Tags: node.js

We are trying to build a system which needs to log the driver's location in real time like Uber. It needs to select the closest, online driver who is free from this data. Our API is built on NodeJS. My biggest concerns are:

- How to log the location in real time.
- How to do this without stressing out the server too much.

For this to work, the driver's mobile app needs to send it's the location to our server every few seconds.

I had a look at PubNub but looks like their mobile SDKs are very old and not maintained. Any other suggestions like that? Or any node packages which can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked [socket.io](https://socket.io/)? if you are already reporting to an endpoint the driver location, whenever you receive the lat, lng, you can send that to all the socket subscribers, who will receive it in realtime.

Comment: Yes looking for a complete framework. If not we'll have to come up with our own solution using sockets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Geolocation Tracking example for Android](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-your-own-uber-lyft-app-geolocation-tracking-android/?devrel_so=55168239) on the PubNub blog. Sending geolocation data from client to server is simple with PubNub.

The client devices can publish the data to 1 or many PubNub channels. The server can subscribe to 1 or all of those channels to listen for publishes as they happen. Message delivery time is generally 80-100ms.

[image: Geolocation Tracking with PubNub Pub/Sub]

**Enable [Wildcard Subscribe](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tech/key-concepts/stream-controller/wildcard-subscribe/?devrel_so=55168239) in the PubNub Admin Dashboard**

The SDKs are maintained, see the changelogs with changes as recent as yesterday.

- https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/changelog?devrel_so=55168239
- https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/changelog?devrel_so=55168239
- https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/changelog?devrel_so=55168239

Also commits are common in the SDK GitHub Repositories.

- https://github.com/pubnub/java
- https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c